# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client with res.writeHead()

Tags: next.js

I am trying to redirect a user to the login if he isn't authenticated. I hardcoded the `jwt` for now. This works, but I only get an error saying `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

Since the function works I don't know what is wrong and couldn't really find an answer to it either. This is my code for reference:

```
function redirectUser(ctx, location) {
  if (ctx.req) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: location });
    ctx.res.statusCode = 302;
    ctx.res.setHeader(302, location);
    ctx.res.end();
    return { props: {} };
  } else {
    Router.push(location);
  }
}

// getInitialProps disables automatic static optimization for pages that don't
// have getStaticProps. So article, category and home pages still get SSG.
// Hopefully we can replace this with getStaticProps once this issue is fixed:
// https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/10949
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const jwt = false;

  // Calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(ctx);
  // Fetch global site settings from Strapi
  const global = await fetchAPI("/global");

  if (!jwt) {
    if (ctx?.ctx.pathname === "/account") {
      redirectUser(ctx.ctx, "/login");
    }
  }

  // Pass the data to our page via props
  return { ...appProps, pageProps: { global } };
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent." means that you're already in the body, but some other function tried to set a header or statusCode. In your case it is the function `ctx.res.setHeader(302, location);`  that's causing the issue.

After writeHead, the headers are baked in and you can only call `res.write(body)`, and finally `res.end(body)`.

You do not need to use `setHeader` when you are already using the `writehead` method.

Read here  more about the [writehead](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers)

So your redirectUser could be like :

```
function redirectUser(ctx, location) {
  if (ctx.req) {
    ctx.res.writeHead(302, { Location: location });
    ctx.res.end();
    return { props: {} };
  } else {
    Router.push(location);
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically I can't use writehead(), but how do I otherwise redirect the user to another page?

Comment: You don't need to  use this `ctx.res.setHeader(302, location);`. I updated my answer where i have removed the `ctx.res.setHeader(302, location);` from the function